# Need to modify HTTP headers to enable the Proxy Auth for Selenium 2.0

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

It requires to inject additional header into the HTTP request to enable proxy auth. E.g.

Proxy-Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0, 
where dGVzdDp0ZXN0 is base64 login and password.

In selenium RC there was such a possibility, but in Selenium 2.0 on RC emulation this does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something similar according to the solution suggested in [How to send an http RequestHeader using Selenium 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6478672/413020)