# Is it possible to open a website in a browser (Chrome/Firefox) using python script?

Tags: python, google-chrome, http, firefox, tcp

When I write address of a website in my browser address bar and click on `Go`, a packet such as below sends out by the browser :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __qca=P0-1436433254-1422702693572; sgt=id=e2dfc663-bf2a-4c13-9387-91db3c901b72; usr=t=5Or7fZxDxUa8&s=xyx0L95dfE61; acct=t=OzuSyto294xCVVgU1B2tOow2C%2bSXqT0m&s=WmMKQ3H9NtZs%2b4%2bfbSnoLretaRnysYju; _ga=GA1.2.1042841397.1422702694
Connection: keep-alive
```

*I catch the above packet using **[BurpSuite tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burp_suite)** and it is a request for StackOverflow.com*

Now I want to know is there any way to automate this request with python?

In the other word, I want to send the above packet with a Python script, and receive the answer in browser (Chrome for example). Is it possible?

**Note:**
I want to modify the packets also. I don't want to send a simple website request only. I want to change some parts of the request packets also. For example in some packets, there is a  parameter named *challenge*, And I want to send request for a website with different challenges. Moreover, assume  that I want to fill a form in a website automatically (Signing up different users for example). (Not exactly by filling the form.By sending the same packet that the browser sends when I click on *Sign Up* or *Confirm* for example)

**Update :**

Actually, I want to do a stress test for a web server. So I want to send a sequence of requests with different headers (i.e. requests for different users) to do a single transaction 1000 times for 1000 different user.Finally I want to see if the transactions done successfully or not. (Assume that the transaction is deposit some money into a single account with different users- So in the end of test I can check the money of that account to see if the transactions done successful or not.) or I can send requests to sign up for different users, and in the end the number of created accounts, will specifies the efficiency of the system in respond of a lot of request.So the response of the web server to my computer is not really important. But if it was possible to see it, It is pleasure

Comment: Use Selenium: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/

Comment: Do you want an actual browser window to be opened or just make the request and read the response? For the first use selenium, for the second use requests

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Please take a look at **Update** section.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium/) to interact with browsers, you can start with [this](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html) page and also you can read the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Below code is a simple usage of selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

try this and enjoy...

Comment: Nice library, Thanks. But is it possible to modify the packets also? I don't want to send a simple website request only. I want to change some parts of the request packets also. For example in some packets, there is a  parameter named _challenge_, And I want to send request for a website with different challenge. Moreover, assume  that I want to fill a form in a website automatically. (Not exactly by filling the form.By sending the same packet that the browser sends when I click on _SignUp_ or _Confirm_ for example)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478672/how-to-send-an-http-requestheader-using-selenium-2/6488092#6488092